# If condition in for loop in Pascal

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, pascal

I have problem. **If** condition in **for** loop is checking only once. What's the problem? Here is my code:

```
program Planas;

function skaiciuoti() : integer;
  var z, zz, d, dt, dp, i, sk : integer;
                       Fr, Fw : text;
  begin
    Assign(Fr, 'Duomenys.txt');
    Reset(Fr);
    ReadLn(Fr, d, z);
    zz := 0;
    dt := d;
    for i := 1 to d do
      begin
        Read(Fr, sk);
        zz := zz + sk;
        if sk >= z then
          dt := d - 1;
      end;
    z := d * z - zz;
    dp := z div d;
    if z mod d <> 0
      then dp := dp + 1;
    Close(Fr);
    WriteLn(dt);
    WriteLn(z);
    WriteLn(dp);
  end;
begin
  skaiciuoti();
  Readln;
end.
```

P.S Thank you for your answers in advance! :)

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: @KenWhite Huh... how to enable debugger in FPS 0.6.4a ?

Comment: What is FPS 0.6.3a? I've never heard of it.

Comment: @KenWhite It's Pascal compilator (Lithuanian version)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you have a typo in your code in `dt := d - 1`. The value of `d` seems to be constant within the loop, so `dt` would not change after the first successful check. I guess you might have wanted to decrement `dt` by using `dt := dt - 1`.